# Kernel version in Lubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: 18.04, kernel

I have recently reinstalled Lubuntu 18.04.1 (amd64) from my original downloaded CD-R.(August 2019). I did this to retain the version 4.15 kernel as my SDR was no longer recognised when 18.04.2 upgraded to the version 5 HWE kernel. After the first software update, a 197MB download, my system now reports the version as 18.04.4, although it still has the non-HWE kernel. Will the non-HWE kernel be retained after further updates?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS can use the original GA kernel (4.15) or the HWE kernel (which will continue to upgrade until it finally reaches the 20.04 kernel in 18.04.5).  Unless you enable HWE you'll stay on the GA (4.15) kernel.   *Installs of 18.04.2 and later default to HWE enabled*  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was puzzled as to why the version now reported as 18.04.04.

Comment: A fully upgraded 18.04 system should report itself as 18.04.4 regardless of what install media is used, or if you *release-upgraded* from a prior 16.04 release to 18.04. HWE or GA kernels are a separate issue to the the release version. You can view the schedule on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseSchedule though installed systems will upgrade to it before listed dates, the date is more the release of the ISO for new installs. You'll note no further ISOs are scheduled for release, but if there is one it'll be 18.04.6 (and your system will auto-update to reflect you at that level)

Comment: In case my point was missed; compare with Xenial's (16.04) - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseSchedule  If you have a fully upgraded Xenial 16.04 system, it'll report you're running 16.04.6 (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) where no .6 release was in the schedule; but just prior to installed 16.04 systems bumped themselves to the new ISO version (16.04.6) when all upgrades were installed (slight delay due to RC testing then ISO is released). The number bumps as new ISOs are spun; reflecting upgrade level of system.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS can use

- the original GA kernel (4.15), or
- the HWE kernel (which will continue to upgrade until it finally reaches the 20.04 kernel in 18.04.5).

Unless you enable HWE you'll stay on the GA (4.15) kernel.
Installs of 18.04.2 and later default to HWE enabled, though systems with HWE can be reverted back to using GA kernel.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack